# Converting date string in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, date, xslt, xslt-2.0

I know there have been similiar posts to this, but I've struggled to find a solution. I have XML data like so:

```
<item>
    <title> A Title </title>
    <link>www.alink.com</link>
    <comments>www.alink.com/cp,,emts</comments>
    <pubDate>Fri, 19 Apr 2013 20:28:39 +0000</pubDate>
    <dc:creator>aUser</dc:creator>
    <category><![CDATA[News]]></category>
    <description><![CDATA["A description"]]></description>
    <content:encoded><![CDATA[content of post]]></content:encoded>
    <wfw:commentRss>www.alink</wfw:commentRss>
    <slash:comments>0</slash:comments>
</item>
```

And my goal is to output to a `div` that has the title with the link value and then the `pubDate` without time. This has been fairly easy, just using this:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
    <div>
        <h5><a href="{link}"><xsl:value-of select="title" /></a> </h5>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="substring(pubDate,1,16)"/></p>
     </div>   
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is I would much like to change the format of the date, and I cannot do it from the source of the XML. I would prefer the format to just be the month, day and year, so `Fri, 19 Apr 2013` would become: `April 19, 2013`.  Any suggestions would be very helpful.

I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: To amplify Jim's question: XSLT 2.0 has facilities for parsing and serializing date formats, while 1.0 does not. So the answer to your question depends greatly on whether you can use 2.0, or are stuck with 1.0.

Comment: Do you really require the ordinal (the `th`) on the day of the month? It is possible but makes things very much more complicated.

Comment: Nope, that is not important at all, I'll edit it out for simplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are solution with xslt version 1.0 and exsl extension.
Without exsl extension and still with version 1.0 the translation from short month to long month name could be done with an xsl:when.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
        extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="month_data_tmp">
        <month short="Apr" long="April" />
        <!--- and so on for each month -->
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="month_data" select="exsl:node-set($month_data_tmp)" />

    <xsl:template match="date" >
        --
        <xsl:call-template name="formate_date" >
            <xsl:with-param name="date" select="pubDate" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="formate_date">
        <xsl:param name="date" />
        <xsl:variable name ="day_str" select="substring-before($date, ',')" />
        <xsl:variable name ="after_day_str" select="substring-after($date, ' ')" />
        <xsl:variable name ="day_nr" select="substring-before($after_day_str, ' ')" />
        <xsl:variable name ="after_day_nr" select="substring-after($after_day_str, ' ')" />
        <xsl:variable name ="month" select="substring-before($after_day_nr, ' ')" />
        <xsl:variable name ="after_month" select="substring-after($after_day_nr, ' ')" />
        <xsl:variable name ="year" select="substring-before($after_month, ' ')" />

        <xsl:value-of select="$month_data/month[@short=$month]/@long"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$day_nr"/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$year"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which generate the output:

```
   April 19, 2013
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Perhaps with xslt version 2.0 there is an shorter version.

Answer (score -1):

With '2.0' we may use format-date function. For more understanding follow this link http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/xml/9780596527211/creating-output/xslt-id-4.5